# /tmp/sqlite-3.7.2-libsqlitejdbc.so: undefined symbol: pthread_mutexattr_init

Tags: linux, sqlite, javafx, jdbc, ormlite

I am working on a JavaFX application in which I am using Ormlite for SQLite database. When I run this application locally in IntelliJ, it works fine. It also works fine when application compiled jar is run. But it is throwing below error, after installing its .deb file and trying to run it.

```
 2018-08-19 15:31:24,763 [INFO] TableUtils creating table 'token'
./wpos: symbol lookup error: /tmp/sqlite-3.7.2-libsqlitejdbc.so: undefined symbol: pthread_mutexattr_init
```

I will add more information if necessary.

Comment: Maybe this is not related, but you are using a very old SQLite version.