# JavaFx with Sqlite database deploy

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, ormlite

I am working on a JavaFX application in which I am using SQLite database for storing some important information. Since I am working on IntelliJ, the created database file is in the root directory of the project.

SQLite database location :

```
jdbc:sqlite:database.db
```

1. But where will be the database after installing with .deb or .exe files by default? In Linux and Windows.
2. How to set a location for a database. So that, that location is going to be the location of the database after installing the application with .deb or .exe files.

Comment: For Windows make sure you have the database in the same folder as the jar. Probably the same for Linux.

Comment: Why is like that ? Any particular reason ? @Sedrick

Comment: I have no clue why they did it. To me, it makes the most logical sense.

Comment: Thanks. @Sedrick, can you please look at this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916618/tmp-sqlite-3-7-2-libsqlitejdbc-so-undefined-symbol-pthread-mutexattr-init

Comment: I saw it already. I haven't used Linux in years. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks friend ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have three options.
the first is to pave the path to the database as an app parameter.

the second option is to use the user's home directory. you can create a subdirectory whose name starts with a dot (hidden directory in linux) in which to put your work files.
to get the name of the home directory use

```
System.getProperty("user.home") ;
```

the last option is to use the directory where the jar file is located

```
MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

Comment: home directory with a dot for Linux. That is fine. What about in Windows?

Comment: @Naroju works under windows too. depending on the version, the home directory is in `c:/users/username` or `c:/documents and settings/username`